# manipulating the format of date on X-axis

Tags: stata, causality

I have a [weekly dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eISttSg3aiXa0L9zisc75sCFi8yYpmma/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100522242107818478356&rtpof=true&sd=true). I use this code to plot the causality between variables. Stata shows the number of weeks of each year on the X-axis. Is it possible to show only year or year-month instead of year-week on the X-axis?

```
generate Date =wofd(D)
format Date %tw
tsset Date
tvgc Momentum supply, p(3) d(3) trend window(25) prefix(_) graph
```

Comment: Please read detailed advice in the Stata tag wiki, notably presenting data examples directly and explaining community-contributed commands you mention (here `tvgc`).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have weekly data is only a distraction here.

You should only use Stata's weekly date functions if your weeks satisfy Stata's rules:

1. Week 1 starts on 1 January, always.
2. Later weeks start 7 days later in turn, except that week 52 is always 8 or 9 days long.
3. Hence there is no week 53.

These are documented rules, and they do not match your data. You are lucky that you have no 53 week years in your data;  otherwise you would get some bizarre results.

See much detailed discussion at references turned up by `search week, sj`.

The good news is that you need just to build on what you have and put labels and ticks on your *x* axis. It's a little bit of work but no more than use of standard and documented label and tick options. The main ideas are blindingly obvious once spelled out:

**Labels** Put informative labels in the middle of time intervals. Suppress the associated ticks. You can suppress a tick by setting its length to zero or its colour to invisible.

**Ticks** Put ticks as the ends (equivalently beginnings) of time intervals. Lengthen ticks as needed.

**Grid lines** Lines demarcating years could be worth adding. None are shown here, but the syntax is just an extension of that given.

**Axis titles** If the time (usually *x*) axis is adequately explained, that axis title is redundant and even dopey if it is some arbitrary variable name.

See especially https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0030 and https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0079

With your data, showing years is sensible but showing months too is likely to produce crowded detail that is hard to read and not much use. I compromised on quarters.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str10 D float(Momentum Supply)
"12/2/2010"    -1.235124   4.760894
"12/9/2010"    -1.537671   3.002344
"12/16/2010"    -.679893  1.5665628
"12/23/2010"    1.964229   .5875537
"12/30/2010"  -1.1872853 -1.1315695
"1/6/2011"    .028031677 .065580264
"1/13/2011"     .4438451  1.2316793
"1/20/2011"    -.3865465  1.7899017
"1/27/2011"    -.4547117   1.539866
"2/3/2011"     1.6675532   1.352376
"2/10/2011"  -.016190516    3.72986
"2/17/2011"     .5471755  2.0804555
"2/24/2011"     .2695233  2.1094923
"3/3/2011"      .5136591 -1.0686383
"3/10/2011"      .606721   3.786967
"3/17/2011"   .004175631   .4544936
"3/24/2011"     1.198901  -.3316304
"3/31/2011"     .1973385   .5846249
"4/7/2011"     2.2470737  1.0026894
"4/14/2011"     .3980386 -2.6676855
"4/21/2011"    -1.530687  -7.214682
"4/28/2011"    -.9735931   3.246654
"5/5/2011"     .13312873   .9581707
"5/12/2011"    -.8017629   -.468076
"5/19/2011"   -.11491735  -4.354526
"5/26/2011"     .3627179  -2.233418
"6/2/2011"     .13805833  2.2697728
"6/9/2011"     .27832976  .58203816
"6/16/2011"   -1.9467738  -.2834298
"6/23/2011"    -.9579238 -1.0356172
"6/30/2011"    1.1799787  1.1011268
"7/7/2011"    -2.0982232   .5292908
"7/14/2011"    -.2992591  -.4004747
"7/21/2011"     .5904395 -2.5159726
"7/28/2011"   -.21626104   1.936029
"8/4/2011"    -.02421602  -.8160484
"8/11/2011"    1.5797064  -.6868965
"8/18/2011"     1.495294 -1.8621664
"8/25/2011"   -1.2188485  -.8388996
"9/1/2011"      .4991612 -1.6689343
"9/8/2011"     2.1691883  1.3244398
"9/15/2011"   -1.2074957   .9707839
"9/22/2011"    -.3399567   .6742781
"9/29/2011"    1.9860272  -3.331345
"10/6/2011"     1.935733  -.3882593
"10/13/2011"   -1.278119   .6796986
"10/20/2011"  -1.3209987   .2258049
"10/27/2011"    4.315368   .7879103
"11/3/2011"    .58669937  -.5040554
"11/10/2011"    1.460597 -2.0426705
"11/17/2011"   -1.338189 -.24199644
"11/24/2011"  -1.6870773 -1.1143018
"12/1/2011"   -.19232976 -1.2156726
"12/8/2011"    -2.655519  -2.054406
"12/15/2011"   1.7161795 -.15301673
"12/22/2011"    -1.43026  -3.138013
"12/29/2011"   .03427247 -.28446484
"1/5/2012"    -.15930523  -3.362428
"1/12/2012"     .4222094  4.0962815
"1/19/2012"    -.2413332  3.8277814
"1/26/2012"    -2.850591 .067359865
"2/2/2012"    -1.1785052  -.3558361
"2/9/2012"    -1.0380571  .05134211
"2/16/2012"     .8539951  -4.421839
"2/23/2012"     .2636529  1.3424703
"3/1/2012"    .022639304   2.734022
"3/8/2012"      .1370547   .8043283
"3/15/2012"     .1787796 -.56465846
"3/22/2012"   -2.0645525 -2.9066684
"3/29/2012"     1.562931  -.4505192
"4/5/2012"     1.2587242  -.6908772
"4/12/2012"   -1.5202224   .7883849
"4/19/2012"    1.0128288 -1.6764873
"4/26/2012"   -.29182148   1.920932
"5/3/2012"     -1.228097 -3.7068026
"5/10/2012"    -.3124508  -3.034149
"5/17/2012"     .7570716 -2.3398724
"5/24/2012"   -1.0697783  -2.438565
"5/31/2012"    1.2796624   1.299344
"6/7/2012"    -1.5482885  -1.228557
"6/14/2012"     1.396692  3.2158935
"6/21/2012"     .3116726   8.035475
"6/28/2012"   -.22332123   .7450229
"7/5/2012"      .4655248  .04986914
"7/12/2012"     .4769497   4.045938
"7/19/2012"    .08743203  .25987592
"7/26/2012"     -.402533   .3213503
"8/2/2012"     -.1564897  1.5290447
"8/9/2012"     -.0919008  .13955575
"8/16/2012"   -1.3851573  1.0860283
"8/23/2012"   .020250637  -.8858514
"8/30/2012"   -.29458764 -1.6602173
"9/6/2012"    -.39921495  -.8043483
"9/13/2012"      1.76396  4.2867813
"9/20/2012"   -1.2335806   2.476225
"9/27/2012"      .176066  -.5992883
"10/4/2012"     .1075483  1.7167135
"10/11/2012"   .06365488  1.1636261
"10/18/2012"   -.2305842  -1.506699
"10/25/2012"   -.1526354  -2.669866
"11/1/2012"   -.06311637 -2.0813057
"11/8/2012"    .55959195   .8805096
"11/15/2012"   1.5306772  -2.708766
"11/22/2012"   -.5585792  .26319882
"11/29/2012" -.035690214 -1.6176193
"12/6/2012"    -.7885767  1.1719254
"12/13/2012"    .9131169 -1.1135346
"12/20/2012"   -.6910864  -.4893669
"12/27/2012"    .9836168   .4052487
"1/3/2013"     -.8828759   .7161615
"1/10/2013"     1.505474  -.1768004
"1/17/2013"   -1.3013282  -1.333739
"1/24/2013"   -1.3670077  1.0568022
"1/31/2013"    .05846912  -.7845241
"2/7/2013"      .4923012  -1.202816
"2/14/2013"   -.06551787  -.9198701
"2/21/2013"   -1.8149366  -.1746187
"2/28/2013"     .3370621  1.0104061
"3/7/2013"     1.2698976   1.273357
"3/14/2013"    -.3884514   .7927139
"3/21/2013"    -.1437847  1.7798674
"3/28/2013"    -.2325031   .9336611
"4/4/2013"     .03971701   .6680117
"4/11/2013"   -.25990707 -3.0261614
"4/18/2013"     .7046488   -.458615
"4/25/2013"   -2.1198323 -.14664523
"5/2/2013"      1.591287  -.3687443
"5/9/2013"    -1.1266721 -2.0973356
"5/16/2013"    -.7595757 -1.1238302
"5/23/2013"    2.2590933   2.124479
"5/30/2013"    -.7447268   .7387985
"6/6/2013"     1.3409324 -1.3744274
"6/13/2013"    -.3844476  -.8341842
"6/20/2013"    -.8135379 -1.7971268
"6/27/2013"    -2.506065  -.4194731
"7/4/2013"     -.4755843  -5.216218
"7/11/2013"    -1.256806  1.8539237
"7/18/2013"   -.13328764 -1.0578626
"7/25/2013"    1.2412375  1.7703875
"8/1/2013"     1.5033063 -2.2505422
"8/8/2013"     -1.291876 -1.5896243
"8/15/2013"    1.0093634 -2.8861396
"8/22/2013"    -.6952878 -.23103845
"8/29/2013"   -.05459245    1.53916
"9/5/2013"     1.2413216    .749662
"9/12/2013"    .19232245    2.81967
"9/19/2013"   -2.6861706  -4.520664
"9/26/2013"     .3105677  -5.274343
"10/3/2013"    -.2184027  -3.251637
"10/10/2013"   -1.233326  -5.031735
"10/17/2013"   1.9415965  -1.250861
"10/24/2013"  -1.2008202 -1.5703772
"10/31/2013"   -.6394427 -1.1347327
"11/7/2013"     2.715824  2.0324607
"11/14/2013"  -1.5833142  2.5080755
"11/21/2013"    .9940037   4.117931
"11/28/2013"   -.8226601   3.752914
"12/5/2013"    .09966203   1.865995
"12/12/2013"  -.18744355  2.5426314
end

gen ddate = daily(D, "MDY") 
gen year = year(ddate)
gen dow = dow(ddate)

tab year 

tab dow 

forval y = 2010/2013 { 
    
    local Y = `y' + 1 
    local yend `yend' `=mdy(1,1,`Y')'

    if `y' > 2010 local ymid `ymid' `=mdy(7,1, `y')' "`y'"
    
    forval q = 1/4 {
        
        if `q' > 4 | `y' > 2010 { 
            local qmid : word `q' of 2 5 8 11
            local qmids `qmids' `=mdy(`qmid', 15, `y')' "Q`q'"
            local qend : word `q' of 4 7 10 4
            local qends `qends' `=mdy(`qend', 1, `y')'
        } 
        
    }
}

line M S ddate, xla(`ymid', tlength(*3) tlc(none)) xtic(`yend', tlength(*5)) xmla(`qmids', tlc(none) labsize(small) tlength(*.5))  xmti(`qends', tlength(*5)) xtitle("") scheme(s1color)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I do not want to plot Momentum and Supply. I want to modify X axis in the rolling causality plot generated by tvgc.

Comment: That is set as an exercise. Either it is a matter of the same principles, or you should report back explaining why the principles don't apply. I decline to be your research assistant to read up on a command you didn't explain to see whether it has different requirements.